# Move toilet rough-in two inches? Floor still open

Tags: toilet

I have just gutted my bathroom and had the plumber move the toilet to a new location.

I just noticed that it is located only 15 inches to center of drain to where the shower glass will be installed. I know that is to code but feel it is too tight and would like to move it to be at least 17 inches away.

How difficult of a job would it be if the floor is still open?
(*It would still be in the same bay and would not hit the next floor joist*).

Photo shows the toilet rough and the pvc pipe to the right is for the sinks.

[image]

Comment: Did you ask the plumber ? He/she would know better then us.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How many pipes are involved here, and how would they be changed?

Comment: @AlaskaMan Yes, plumber would know best but was afraid to ask.

Comment: @DanielGriscom It is just the toilet waste line since I believe the supply would still reach.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could fit an Offset Flange there. You'd probably get about 1.5".
[image: https://www.homedepot.com/p/NIBCO-3-in-x-4-in-PVC-DWV-Hub-Offset-Closet-Flange-C4848AHD43/100347580]
[Home Depot - NIBCO 3 in. x 4 in. PVC DWV Hub Offset Closet Flange](https://www.homedepot.com/p/NIBCO-3-in-x-4-in-PVC-DWV-Hub-Offset-Closet-Flange-C4848AHD43/100347580)

Comment: Thank you. Just worried about some of the negative feedback regarding offset flanges.

Comment: An offset flange is going to be easier than getting under the floor and messing with it. Any more and we start adding pipe or elbows.